# Failed Update with Bitlocker enabled

Tags: windows-10, updates, bitlocker

My laptop failed to update and I have BitLocker enabled. Now my winloader.efi is corrupted and I cannot fix it without the recovery key. The problem is that I accidentally flashed the drive with the key on it. I remember the password and I installed windows on a secondary drive and tried the CMD prompt "manage-bde -unlock E: -pw" type in the password and I receive the following output "ERROR: The password failed to unlock volume E:" Short of going down the dubious route of imaging and trying to crack is there a way to get into my files? I have a paper due next Sunday and I really don't want to have to rewrite it. Ironically it was a paper based on cyberlaw vs morality.

Comment: Was the disk protected using a basic password, or using TPM? Have you checked https://account.microsoft.com/devices/recoverykey for key backup?

Comment: There isn’t anything that can be done without the recovery key